# How do write code to get a count of how many times a particular div occurs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write code to count how much times a div (with class) occurs

**EXAMPLE**

**HTML**

```
<div class = "list">
  <p> more info</p>
</div>

<div class = "list">
  <p> more info</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var listCount = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
console.log(listCount);
```

//I know this is wrong but I'm not sure what to use

The result I'm expecting is **2**

Comment: You are so close! Great job. The answer is in the `length` property of `listCount`. So use `listCount.length`

Comment: Thanks, @RandyCasburn :) ...smh...can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the length. The way your current code is setup you will just get the dom elements. Just append .length to your listCount to get the actual count (note it returns an array of dom elements).

```js
var listCount = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
console.log(listCount.length);
```

```html
x<div class = "list">
  <p> more info</p>
</div>

<div class = "list">
  <p> more info</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use length to get the count:

```
console.log(listCount.length);
```